# JQuery: Reference appended object thru appended object

Tags: jquery

I have a button that append a text input field.

```
<button id="addD">Add D</button>
```

Clicking this button will append a textfield and a `<h3>` tag.

```
    <script>
    var dNum=1;
    function addW(){
        $('#tableW').append('<tr><td><h3 id="wd'+dNum+'"></h3></tr>');
    }
    $('#addD').click(function(){
        $('#divD').append('<input type="text" class="dName" id="d'+dNum+'">');
        addW();
        dNum++;
    });
    </script>
```

Now I want a change on the appended textfield to reflect on the appended `<h3>` tag.
I tried doing this:

```
    $(document).on('change', '.dName', function(){ //when input field change
        var h3ID = 'w'+$(this).attr('id');
        var h3Tag = document.getElementById(h3ID);
        h3Tag.firstChild.nodeValue = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')).value;
    });
```

The referenced text does not get changed. Is there anyway that I can reference the specific `<h3>` tag with the corresponding id? I think the problem lies on the tag being appended and since no action is required to act on it, the .on() seems irrelevant.

Comment: Could you show a working example? Fiddle?

Comment: Jamie thanks for looking at my post! The solution is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use raw javascript dom manipulation since you are using jQuery.

You can easily get reference to the `h3` using the `id` and then change the contents using the `html()` method provided by jQuery.

```
$(document).on('change', '.dName', function(){ //when input field change
    var h3ID = 'w'+$(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + h3ID).html($(this).val());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Tpyck/)

Comment: I have been searching for hours. Your solution works! Really grateful.

Comment: sorry, I am new to posting question. Accepted. Thank you once again.

Comment: or simply: `$(document).on('change', '.dName', function () { $('#w' + $(this).attr('id')).text($(this).val());});`

Answer (score 0):

A clearer approach to control items:

```
var dNum=1;
function addW(){
    var $h3 = $('h3');
    $h3.attr('id', dNum);
    var $elem = $elem.wrap('<td>').wrap('<tr>');
    $elem.on('change', function() { // do something on change});

    $('#tableW').append($elem);
}
```